# Easiest way to make new partitions?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning

I'm not really tech savvy so simple explanations please!

So at the moment I'm having 240GB SSD, I'm running Ubuntu 16.04 and Windows 7.
I have 2 partitions. 100GB for Ubuntu and 140GB for Windows. But I would like to change it so Ubuntu would have 25GB, Windows 100GB and remaining 115GB would be it's own partition so both OS can access it easily.
Can I make this change while these two OS installed or do I have to reinstall them and while doing it, make three different partitions?
And I tried search before but I didn't really find similiar situation.

Edit: and if I have to install these OS again, can I make a backup of current setups and restore them in new partitions? And I should make the partitions during Windows install?

Comment: take a look at [gparted](http://gparted.org/display-doc.php%3Fname%3Dmoving-space-between-partitions)

Answer (score 1):

I'd highly recommend runnning

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt install gparted
```

then running "gparted" from your start (after entering your password) it'll open this :

[image: gparted up and running]

From here you can select your hard drive, you'll be able to tell which is which mainly from the size but the partition types also help.

From there interactively either with the list or with the graphic you may resize partitions (even live ones) to create empty space. and create a new partition in that empty space.

The green check mark or "Apply" is required for the changes to take place.

I recommend the partition type both would use be NTFS. Windows cannot read EXT4 (or even 3) to save it's life. I know there are multiple apps meant to do this but none of them work any longer.

EX4 is better than NTFS but ubuntu reads/writes to NTFS as well if not better than windows itslef. Only hold-up being windows locks all NTFS drives by default on reboot/shutdown.

Typing `powercfg -h off` into an Admin CMD (windows-side) before you reboot your windows will prevent that but if that's a hassle just make a FAT32 partition which is the most neutral type there is and any os can read/write to it.

If I'm being honest here I don't think you should make a seperate partition for file sharing between windows and linux. To save time just make your "shared space" the entire windows partition. You can easily do the command I listed above and you only need to retype it every time windows updates.

And you can create shortcuts straight to your "My Pictures", "My Documents", ect... folders within your windows partition in your ubuntu very easily. This will save you the time of copying the files to and fro from partitions.

Say, for example, you have Myresume.docx that is editable/openable by libre office without jumbling it up. You can boot to ubuntu open the file where it sits in your windows "My Documents", edit it, save it reboot to windows and repeat the process there with word and you don't loose any time.

Answer (score 1):

> Can I make this change while these two OS installed

Yes. [Gparted](http://gparted.org/display-doc.php%3Fname%3Dmoving-space-between-partitions) is the tool in Linux to do this with. You can also do this from Windows but be careful: Windows does not tell you about foreign operating systems and Gparted does.

Mind though (some things you might already know but just in case):

- Use the gparted live session from the link to do this (works the same way as the Ubuntu installer but will show you gparted when booted). You can only change partitions that are not mounted so that makes it easier to use.
- Operations on partitions are best to do 1 at a time.
- Shrink the Ubuntu partition.
- Format the unallocated space to NTFS. The partition you want to use to share between the 2 needs to be formatted with a filesystem Windows supports (so NTFS is the most obvious to pick).
- Ubuntu/Linux will refuse to mount NTFS if you use hibernation when turning Windows off and booting directly to Ubuntu.